# ant-design collapse ,only one paneland it's content should show at a time

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using ant-design collapse so when I expand particular panel ,only that particular panel and it's content should display and other panels should not show at all,when I click on collpase only all panel should show,how to achieve this.

I'm using accordian here,

this is the link
https://ant.design/components/collapse/

But here when I click on partiular panel it's content is showing and also other panel is appearing, but I want other panels also should not show

Thank you

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: example mentioned for accordian in the url , working as expected..displaying only one panel content.. check the antd version you are using